# Dataflow Template - No template found at the specified path / The metadata file is malformed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataprep

Creating a Dataflow job from a Dataflow template, which was created by a Dataprep job run.

Two warnings/errors show when using the template path:

```
No template found at the specified path.
The metadata file is malformed.
```

You can also see this in the screenshot below.

[image]

This Dataprep/dataflow job has been running for months unmodified. When I search for the starting file name of the job template in my Google Cloud Storage, it does not show up. The job just ran this morning successfully.

Anyone have an idea why the template doesn't exist or there is this metadata error?